# Windows group policy settings are not replicating to other DC (windows 2019)

Tags: group-policy, domain-controller

I have a scenario where group policy settings are not replicating from primary DC01 to backup DC02.

Please see in the picture attached below showing the same exact GPO policy being viewed from both DCs. A policy set on DC01 does not replicate in DC02.

Maybe more importantly policies set on DC01 are not being updated on member servers with gpupdate /force. But if I set the policy on DC02 it is being updated on the member servers with gpupdate /force.

gpresult /r shows "Group Policy was applied from: DC02.mydom.com" even if ENV:LOGONSERVER is showing \\DC01.The only way I can get policies to come from DC01 is to turn off DC02.

any advice would be greatly appreciated! thanks

[image: GPEditor-Both-DCs]

Comment: I would run from the DC you made the changes, `repadmin /syncall /AdeP` first. Then refresh the GPO and then drill down and look at it again. The repadmin command should tell the DC to replicate with all it's partners. Sometimes I wrap that command in an invoke-command and run it against each DC one after then other to speed up replication. Not sure how fast your network links are between the DCs or applicable sites, I assume it's just a wait deal when replication occurs but that might speed it up for you.

Comment: Really hard to troubleshoot this without seeing the system. Are you using DFSR for SYSVOL replication yet? Is AD replication working without issues? Do replication links exist between the two domain controllers? Are both DCs in the same site or different sites? What happens when you replicate manually between the domain controllers? Possible to demote and promote the domain controller again?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check both AD and SYSVOL replication status.

`repadmin /showreps` on both DCs to verify AD replication.

You can use DFS Diag management console to verify SYSVOL status.

If AD replication is ok, worst case scenario is you can reinitialize SYSVOL and force an authoritative replication on DC2 from the PDCe DC1. SYSVOL is typically small and the process completes quickly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/group-policy/force-authoritative-non-authoritative-synchronization